# How to include JavaScript in onRequestStart() of Application.cfc

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion, application.cfc

I have an `onRequestStart()` as follows

```
<cffunction name="onRequestStart" access="public" returntype="boolean" output="false" hint="initializes the request">
    <cfif deployment.DBFlag eq 'Live' >
        <cfset REQUEST.DataSource = deployment.LiveDSN>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset REQUEST.DataSource = deployment.TestDSN>
    </cfif>
    <cfset REQUEST.ServerBasePath = deployment.ServerBasePath>
    <cfif not listContains(APPLICATION.ListOfFile,Trim(cgi.script_name))>
        <cfif not isDefined("SESSION.UID")>
            <cflogout>
            <cflocation url="/rpnet-ROI/loginform.cfm" addtoken="no">
        </cfif>
    </cfif>

    <!--- Return true so the page can process. --->
    <cfreturn true />
</cffunction>
```

I need to reload my page once the session id is not defined.
Is it possible to include javascript in Application.cfc?
If yes, how can we do that else do we need to include a cfm file containing javascript code in it.

The code I need to include in the JavaScript is:

```
<script>parent.location.reload(true);</script>
```

Comment: Why do you need that JavaScript? I see that you have a `<cflocation>` already. That should redirect the user's browser to the login form. Is it not working? You probably need to `<cfreturn false />` to stop any further processing and just send the redirect headers.

Comment: I have used iFrames for my application...So when a user logs out from one page it is fine....but from other tab upon logout it leads to loginpage within iframe itself.

So to reload the whole page on logout i need to reload the full page on logout parent.location.reload..That is why I need it at onRequestStart

Comment: Just to be clear: on the client side your app makes use of multiple browser tabs, or just one tab with an I frame inside?

Comment: just one tab with an Iframe inside

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible to include JavaScript in Application.cfc. The code inside the methods of Application.cfc occur server side and has no way to call code on the client side. Specifically, `onRequestStart()` runs once the request is made to the server. There is no response from the server at this point, so there is nothing for the client to be able to display/act on.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Is there any other way I can do that?

Comment: I have to be honest, I am not sure I fully understand what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I think he's trying to verify a user is logged in on certain pages. Hence the "cfif not listContains(APPLICATION.ListOfFile,Trim(cgi.script_name))" > Logout.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `parent.location.reload(true);` into the login page's `window.onload()` method, wrapped within a check to see if you are actually inside an iframe (if the login page can also be called outside of an iframe).

Comment: Thanks a lot... :)
The most easiest way...exact solution to my problem

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, please mark the answer correct so others can find the solution later.  Thanks